# How can i achive atomicity just like django orm in fastapi with sqlalchmey orm

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, fastapi

How can i achive atomicity just like django orm in fastapi with sqlalchmey orm.
What i am trying to do is making a cron script which will delete data from s3 bucket and DB a lot of data. If some how s3 operation fails and it creates inconsistency or either case s3 pass and DB fails. So I want to achive atomicity like we have in django "with atomic transactions".

What i am trying to do is making a cron script which will delete data from s3 bucket and DB a lot of data.

Comment: Try db.session.rollback using flask and sqlalchemy. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be this way,

```py
def function_name(...):
   try:
       ...
       db.commit()
   except:
       db.rollback()
   finally:
       db.close()
```